# C# Изменить содержимое тега textarea

Tags: c#, winforms

(C#) Собственно пользуюсь WebBrowser в WindowsForm. Спокойно заполнял данные форм на странице пока не дошел до этого:

```
<textarea id="q" placeholder="Enter your quote...">Вот тут должен быть текст,но его там нет</textarea>
```

Как изменить содержимое тега? Пробовал делать, как делал до этого:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("q").InnerText="Мой текст";
```

Но при таком методе он изменяет placeholder, а не само содержимое тега.

UPD. Решил проблему сам, изменил атрибут value...

Comment: попробуй сделать так:

`webBrowser1.Document.GetElementByTagName("textarea").InnerText="Мой текст";`

Comment: Абсолютно тот же результат

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> .InnerText
> ```

Это содержимое обычных dom-элементов, а у контролов

```
.Value
```